# Why is GWT removing client logging in production mode?

Tags: gwt, logging

I've followed the GWT docs on client-side logging and have it working fine in dev mode. I have it enabling the `ConsoleHandler`, `FirebugHandler`, and `RemoteHandler`. The `RemoteHandler` is working fine; I've added the `RemoteLoggingServlet` and it's working fine in dev mode as well.

here is the relevant excerpt from my *.gwt.xml :

```xml
<inherits name="com.google.gwt.logging.Logging"/>

<set-property name="gwt.logging.logLevel" value="ALL"/>
<set-property name="gwt.logging.enabled" value="TRUE"/> 
<set-property name="gwt.logging.popupHandler" value="DISABLED" />
<set-property name="gwt.logging.simpleRemoteHandler" value="ENABLED" />
<set-property name="gwt.logging.consoleHandler" value="ENABLED" />
<set-property name="gwt.logging.firebugHandler" value="ENABLED" />
<set-property name="gwt.logging.developmentModeHandler" value="DISABLED" />
```

and my client code does this :

```java
Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("");
logger.log(Level.ALL, "Hey log this message");
```

None of the logging is working in production mode. Is there a setting somewhere I am missing?

Comment: Logging with an `ALL` level looks suspicious to me. What are `SEVERE`, `WARN`, `FINE` or `FINER` doing?

Comment: It is working fine after all.  I was looking at the wrong web app context and so was looking at an earlier version of the app, which had no logging. Once I was looking at the right app, the client logging was working fine in production mode as well. But thanks for your attention.